# How to consolidate the multiple j query scripts I have on the page into one?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, performance

I have eight separate scripts in my page to add the slideToggle() behavior to eight different elements. Is there anyway to consolidate it into one single script so that it does not as severely impact page load times?

```
<div id="proficiencies_holder">
    <div id="proficiencies_menu">
        [insert_php] 
            $args = array('category_name'=>'competencies-and-domains','posts_per_page'=> -1);
            $query = new WP_Query($args);
            $i = 0;
            while($query->have_posts()):
                $i+=1;
                $query->the_post();
                $div_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()),'full');
                echo '<div class="prof_menu_item_holder">';
                echo '<div id="prof_button'.$i.'"class="prof_menu_item custom-parallax"style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.3),rgba(0,0,0,.3)),url('.$div_image[0].')">';
                echo get_the_title();
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div id="par_tab'.$i.'">';
                echo get_the_content();
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<script>$(document).ready(function(){$("#prof_button'.$i.'").click(function(){$("#par_tab'.$i.'").slideToggle();});});</script>';
            endwhile;
        [/insert_php]
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use classes? ex: prof_button and par_tab

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".prof_button").click(function(){
          $(this).next('.par_tab').slideToggle();
     });
});
```

demo: http://codepen.io/biancamihai/pen/rVXoaW

Comment: If I used classes every one of the divs would be toggled if I clicked any one of the buttons. They are each linked to a specific content div.

Comment: not every div will be toggled just the next div to the one that is clicked, you have ```$(this).next('.par_tab').slideToggle();```

Comment: I added a demo in the answer

Comment: Ohhh ok so If I use .next() it will only apply to the next element from that class on the page. Thank you for that lol; Im still trying to learn jquery.

Comment: check out the documentation https://api.jquery.com/next/ in this case ```$(this).next('.par_tab').slideToggle();``` - toggle the next div with the class ```par_tab``` (next related to the clicked div) http://codepen.io/biancamihai/pen/rVXoaW

Comment: Thank you, I probably wouldn't have figured that out on my own. I'm relatively new to web design.

Comment: Sorry had a lecture right after posting this and forgot